# Jquery only fired when changing one select input but not the other select tags

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

for a users table, I'm trying to dynamically create a feature which allows the admin person to change the user's role from the table by clicking the select tag and changing the the role from the list of the roles provided which would fire the JQuery at the bottom with an AJAX called. The problem is, it is only responding to just one select tag on the table which is the one at the top row. I have someone understanding of what is wrong but have no idea how to resolve it. I think I need to loop through the events and listen to which is firing but I do not know how to implement that. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<tbody>
            <?php while ($all_admins = mysqli_fetch_assoc($admins)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="<?php echo url_for('../images/staff/'.$all_admins['image'])?>" onerror="this.src='<?php echo url_for('../images/staff/profile.jpg') ?>'" style="border:1px solid #ddd;border-radius:2px; box-shadow: #4a5f63; height: 70px;width: 70px"></td>
                    <td><?php echo h($all_admins['first_name']) ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo h($all_admins['last_name']) ?></td>
                    <td><a class='btn btn-info' href="staff.php?source=show_staff&staff_id=<?php echo h($all_admins['id']) ?>"> <?php echo h($all_admins['email']) ?> </a></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                                $role = $all_admins['role'];
                                switch ($role){
                                    case 'DE':
                                        echo "Data Entry";
                                        break;
                                    case 'GU':
                                        echo "General User";
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        echo "Administrator";
                                        break;
                                }
                        ?>
                        <span>
                            <select id="urole" name="role[]">
                                            <option value="Admin" <?php echo ($role == 'Admin')?'selected':'' ?> >Admin</option>
                                            <option value="DE" <?php echo ($role == 'DE')?'selected':'' ?> >Data Entry</option>
                                            <option value="GU" <?php echo ($role == 'GU')?'selected':'' ?> >General User</option>
                            </select>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><a class='btn btn-info' href="staff.php?source=edit_staff&staff_id=<?php echo h($all_admins['id']) ?>">Edit</a></td>
                    <form method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php //echo $post_id ?>">

                        <?php
                        echo '<td><input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"></td>';

                        ?>

                    </form>

                </tr>

  $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        
        $("#urole").change(function (){
            var val = $("#urole option:selected").val();
            console.log(val);
            // $("#urole").on('click', function(){
            //     v
            // });

            //displayData(val);
        });

        $("#urole").ready(function (){
            var val = $("#urole option:selected").val();
            console.log(val);
            //displayData(val);
        });

    });
    function displayData(query){
        $.ajax({
            url:"enrolled_learners/enrol_learner_provider.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{query:query},
            success:function (data)
            {
                //console.log(data);
                $('#q-provider').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're using duplicate ids which is not valid. element ids must be unique. As such `$("#urole")` is internally designed to return only one element. Instead, you should use a common class on these elements and use `$(".urole")` to target all elements that have that class.

Change your form to

```
<select class="urole" name="role[]">
```

And your jQuery to:

```
  $("#urole").change(function (){
        var val = $(this).val();
        console.log(val);
        displayData(val);
   });
```

Comment: Hi, it does make a change but the behaviour is not what is expected. Changing the first row of the table tends to still impact other rows which is a behaviour that I do not want to happen. If I change the first-row select to say Data Entry and then change the subsequent rows. The console still logs the value of the select statement in the table's first row. Which is not the expected behaviour, because I do not want other rows to affect by changing the role in other rows of the table. The reason is that I am sending the change via ajax to update a table in the database.

Comment: The idea is allowing the system admin to change the role of a user dynmically from the table by just selecting the options given

Comment: See my update above, inside the handler you can use `$(this).val()` to get the value of the selected option but to be honest, that sounds like a completely new question. Perhaps if you start a new question that shows your php code and explain exactly what you're seeing happen we could help better with that issue. I suspect that what you need to do to fix that is send `$all_admins['id']` along with the new `role` to `enrol_learner_provider.php` so that script knows what user to apply the new role value to in the db,  but Id need to see the code to say for sure